# copying files from recursive directory to a folder with find command on Jupyter

Tags: find

In my current directory, I have several subfolders. I want to copy all the files from subfolders into just one folder called 'data'. I am working with python3, Jupyter notebook on a remote. Inside the jupyter script, using;

```
!find . -name "*.*" -exec cp {} path/to/data \;
```

Why it is not working? It did not give error or anything, it looks like running but no file is copied yet when I refresh the data folder. thanks

Comment: Are you sure you only want files with `.` somewhere in the name?  `find . -type f -execdir cp -n "{}" /path/to/data \;` should do the trick.  (`cp -n` is used to not clobber existing files in the event of duplicate filenames)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have found another method than find.